# function' object has no attribute 'create_order'

Tags: django

I'm having some trouble understanding "import"

This piece of code works properly.  I

```
from checkout import create_order

# Create your views here.
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':


        create_order(request)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/menu/')


    return render_to_response("payment_form.html",locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but for some reason this code gives me the error: (function' object has no attribute 'create_order' )

```
import checkout

# Create your views here.
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':


        checkout.create_order(request)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/menu/')


    return render_to_response("payment_form.html",locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

shouldn't it work the same?

this is the create order function

```
from cart import cart
from models import Order, OrderItem
from django.core import urlresolvers
import urllib


def create_order(request): 
    order = Order()

    order.user = request.user
    order.status = Order.SUBMITTED

    #have this fix this
    order.time = 7

    order.save()

    # if the order save succeeded 
    if order.pk:
        cart_items = cart.get_cart_items(request) 
        for ci in cart_items:
            # create order item for each cart item 
            oi = OrderItem()
            oi.order = order
            oi.quantity = ci.quantity
            oi.price = ci.price # now using @property oi.product = ci.product
            oi.product = ci.product
            oi.save()

        # all set, empty cart
        cart.empty_cart(request) 

    # return the new order object 
    return order
```

this is an img of my files
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
import checkout

# Create your views here.
def checkout(request):
```

Your function has the same name as the module, so this is trying to call a function on the function `checkout`:

```
checkout.create_order(request)
```